# Regaining access to server after I banned myself with denyhosts

Tags: denyhosts

I have installed DenyHosts 2 days ago and I didn't added my IP to list of safe IPs. Today I connected my server but it struggled a bit and I had to terminate my application which I connect to server. After that I got banned from my own server. I can still access full FTP but I can't edit hosts.deny

Is there any way that I can regain access to my server?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting from another IP? If not, I would try connecting from another IP, you can either ssh from another server or goto McDonalds and use their free WiFi.

In the future, you can avoid getting locked out / banned again by adding your ip to the `hosts.allow` list.